# How To Send File To Action With JQuery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I want to send txt file to action and get text words count without submiting form.

my codes in action works well (this action get HttpPostedFileBase and using with stream reader return count)so problem is in View.

this is My Code in View to send file to view and get result:

```
<script>

    $("#MyForm").submit(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var files = $('#fileInput').files[0]);

        $.ajax({
            type: "Post",
            url: "/Counter/GetCount",
            enctype: "multipart/form-data",
            data: files
        }).done(function (result) {

            $("#result").html(result);

        });
</script>
```

if you can, fix my code or give me new code i want to see your suggestions for doing this.

**Edit** code from comment:

```
[HttpPost] 
public ActionResult GetCount(HttpPostedFileBase file) 
{ 
  using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(file.FileName)) 
  { 
    string result = reader.ReadToEnd(); 
    return PartialView(result.Count()); 
  } 
}
```

Comment: If your problem is in the view then showing us the jquery won't help.  What exactly is `result` in your `.done` function.  Does it hit .done or do you get an error (always add a `.fail` call).   If you're just counting words, why not do it in the js?  (or is this just a proof-of-concept)?

Comment: we also need to see the action in the backend

Comment: @freedomn-m result is count of text...and this is just for training

Comment: @JonathanAlfaro         `        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult GetCount(HttpPostedFileBase file)    
        {
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(file.FileName))
            {
                string result = reader.ReadToEnd();
                return PartialView(result.Count());
            }
        }`

Comment: The action should receive an IFormFile

Comment: @JonathanAlfaro its in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http name space but my project is in Asp .Net Mvc?

Comment: it is either .net core or not..... and IFormFile is the right type to receive when uploading files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use FormData to pass files to action with ajax.Here is a working demo:

view:

```
<form id="MyForm" method="post">
    <input id="fileInput" type="file" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
<script>
        $("#MyForm").submit(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var formData = new FormData();
            formData.append('file', $('#fileInput').get(0).files[0]);
            $.ajax({
                type: "Post",
                url: "/Counter/GetCount",
                data: formData,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
            }).done(function (result) {

                $("#result").html(result);

            });
        })
    </script>
```

Action:

```
[HttpPost] 
public ActionResult GetCount(IFormFile file) 
{ 
  using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(file.FileName)) 
  { 
    string result = reader.ReadToEnd(); 
    return PartialView(result.Count()); 
  } 
}
```

Result:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try to replace ajax request code with:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "/Counter/GetCount",
  data:files,
  type:'POST',
  contentType: false,
  processData: false,
  success: function(result){
    $("#result").html(result);
  }
});
```